# Скрывающееся боковое меню (bootstrap, css)

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap, sass, navigationbar

Как сделать желательно без применения js боковое меню на сайте?

Задачи следующие:

- меню на 100% `height` экрана
- в меню иконки разделов и соответствующие названия
- вверху  логотип и стрелка для скрытия меню (в скрытом состоянии видны только логотипы, при наведении курсора появляется название пункта, логотип также скрыт)
- в размерах `md - lg` видно все меню, в размерах `xs - sm` только логотипы изначально и можно развернуть.

Лично для себя интересно можно ли выполнить данный элемент без JS на чистом CSS. В туториалах в целом видел подобные варианты через `:checked` псевдо селектор

Answer (score 1):

Может так попробовать?

```css
.menu {
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.menu li {
  background-color: #d4d6d8;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.menu li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.menu a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.menu a::before {
  content:"♘";
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  color: #6fa0f2;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.ctrl {
  display: none;
}

.logo,
label {
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  background: #6fa0f2;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.ctrl:checked ~ .menu span{
  display: none;
}

.menu a:hover .text-ref{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <label for="ctrl">&dArr;</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="ctrl" id="ctrl">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="text-ref">Пункт 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="text-ref">Пункт 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="text-ref">Пункт 3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="text-ref">Пункт 4</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="text-ref">Пункт 5</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```